# What is the best way to download a file with a speed limit using NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, python-requests, download

I am trying to figure out the best way to download files with a speed limit using NodeJS's builtin HTTPS module. (There is a fully working python implementation of what I am trying to do at the bottom.) I have written two different functions and both of them seem to get the job as expected.

`download1` function, checks whether the speed limit has been exceeded in the current second and if so, pauses the download and creates a timeout that gets triggered at the end of that second that resumes the download.

`download2` however, instead of creating a timeout, creates an interval that gets triggered once every 1000 miliseconds and resumes the download if it has been paused.

I was wondering which one of these two approaches is better or if I should go about it with a whole diffent approach.

Here are the functions:

```js
export const download1 = (url: string, fileName: string, speedLimitInKb: number) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, _reject) => {
        https.get(url, res => {
            const stream = fs.createWriteStream(fileName);
            let totalSize = 0;
            let size = 0;
            let speedLimit = kbToBytes(speedLimitInKb);
            let startDate: number;
            let lastSecond = Date.now();

            res.pipe(stream);

            res.once("resume", () => {
                startDate = Date.now();
                console.log(`Started at ${new Date(startDate)}`)
            })

            res.on("data", (chunk) => {
                size += chunk.length;
                const now = Date.now();
                if (now - lastSecond > 1000) {
                    lastSecond = Date.now();
                    totalSize += size;
                    size = 0;
                } else if (size >= speedLimit) {
                    res.pause();
                    setTimeout(() => res.resume(), 1000 - (now - lastSecond));
                }
            });

            res.on("resume", () => {
                lastSecond = Date.now();
                totalSize += size;
                size = 0;
            })

            res.on("end", () => {
                const elapsed = (Date.now() - startDate) / 1000;
                totalSize += size
                stream.end();
                console.log(`${bytesToMb(totalSize)} mb of data downloaded in ${elapsed} seconds with a speed of ${bytesToKb(totalSize) / elapsed}`)
                resolve(undefined);
            });

            res.on("error", console.log);
        })
    })
};
```

```js
export const download2 = (url: string, fileName: string, speedLimitInKb: number) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, _reject) => {
        https.get(url, res => {
            const stream = fs.createWriteStream(fileName);
            let totalSize = 0;
            let size = 0;
            let speedLimit = kbToBytes(speedLimitInKb);
            let startDate: number;
            res.pipe(stream);

            res.once("resume", () => {
                startDate = Date.now();
                console.log(`Started at ${new Date(startDate)}`)
            })

            const interval = setInterval(() => {
                if (res.isPaused()) {
                    res.resume();
                }
                totalSize += size;
                size = 0;
            }, 1000);

            res.on("data", (chunk) => {
                size += chunk.length;
                if (size >= speedLimit) {
                    res.pause();
                }
            });

            res.on("end", () => {
                clearInterval(interval);
                const elapsed = (Date.now() - startDate) / 1000;
                totalSize += size
                stream.end();
                console.log(`${bytesToMb(totalSize)} mb of data downloaded in ${elapsed} seconds with a speed of ${bytesToKb(totalSize) / elapsed}`)
                resolve(undefined);
            });

            res.on("error", console.log);
        });
    })
}
```

Additional functions:

```js
export const bytesToKb = (bytes: number) => bytes / 1024;
export const kbToMb = (kb: number) => kb / 1024;
export const kbToBytes = (kb: number) => kb * 1024;
export const mbToKb = (mb: number) => mb * 1024;
export const mbToBytes = (mb: number) => mb * 1024 * 1024;
export const bytesToMb = (bytes: number) => bytes / 1024 / 1024;
export const bytesToGb = (bytes: number) => bytes / 1024 / 1024 / 1024;
export const secondsToMs = (seconds: number) => seconds * 1000;
export const msToSeconds = (ms: number) => ms / 1000;
```

I have written a Python version of what I am trying to achieve and this works with any speed limit and file size. I would like to figure out how I can implement this in nodejs:

```py
import requests
import time

def download(url, file_name, speed_limit_in_kb):
    start = time.time()
    size = 0
    total_size = 0
    with open(file_name, "wb") as f:
        with requests.get(url, stream=True) as res:
            last_second = time.time()
            for part in res.iter_content(1024):
                f.write(part)
                total_size += len(part)
                size += len(part)
                offset = time.time() - last_second
                if offset > 1:
                    size = 0
                    last_second = time.time()
                elif size > (1024 * speed_limit_in_kb):
                    time.sleep(1 - offset)
                    size = 0
                    last_second = time.time()
    elapsed = time.time() - start
    print(f"{total_size / 1024 / 1024} mb of data downloaded in {elapsed} seconds with a speed of {total_size / 1024 / elapsed}")
```

Comment: What do you mean by "speed limit" and why?  A server that is doing proper networking and flow control should not have to worry about sending or receiving data too quickly.

Comment: @jfriend00 Because I don't want one download using up all of my bandwidth. For instance, when you are playing an online game, if you download something in the background, your ping will be very high, but if you limit it to half of your bandwidth, the ping increase won't be as much.

Comment: FYI, I actually ran your first version (after guessing at the implementation of your missing conversion functions) and it does not appear to do what it implies it is supposed to do.  I pass in a URL to a 3.5MB image, a local filename and `speedLimitInKb` of `100` and it tells me this" `3.85 mb of data downloaded in 1.127 seconds with a speed of 3494.2590949423247` which does not seem to be implementing the speed limit properly.  I do see that is paused the readstream a number of times but did not slow it down very much.

Comment: If you really want to force it to slow down to the passed in rate, then you will need a significantly different implementation.  Perhaps what you have here solves your problem just because it does insert stream pauses, but the logic does not actually limit the download to the passed in rate at all.

Comment: @jfriend00 My bad, i forgot to share the additional functions, i have added them. And I actually had not tried with small files and turns out you are right. It doesn't work when the file size is smaller or slightly bigger than the bandwidth speed. The larger the file, the more accurately it works but ideally, it should work in all scenarios. That is why I posted this question, to find out a better way. Here are some samples with a larger file:
https://prnt.sc/26u2u9f
http://prnt.sc/26u2ulh
https://prnt.sc/26u2uqd

Comment: There's more to it than small files slightly bigger than the bandwidth speed.  For example, if you get a chunk that is larger than the speedLimit, you pause and set a timer, but you don't take into consideration at all how big the chunk was in setting the timer that you just got.  As an example, what if your speedLimit was 1000 and you got a chunk that was 65536 bytes long that arrived in very little time.  You need to pause for awhile to get down to that speedLimit and how long you need to wait is dependent upon how much over the speedLimit you were.  But, you don't factor that in at all.

Comment: I think if I were implementing this, on each `data` event, I'd push into an array the time that it arrived and the number of bytes of the chunk.  Then, you can write yourself a function that, starting at the end of the array and working towards the front of the array, calculates a rolling average speed over any time period that is relevant (say over the last N seconds).  If that rolling average is above your speedLimit, then you pause the stream for as long as you need to for the existing rolling average to get back to or below your speedLimit.

Comment: @jfriend00 You are right. This will fail if the speed limit is bigger than chunk length. I have now added a Python implementation of what I am trying to achieve and my tests show that it works no matter how low or high I set the speed limit or no matter how small or big the file is. But this is easy to do in Python because you are just iterating through the stream as you like. Nodejs however, works with events so I can't follow this approach.

Comment: A further turn of events, `res.pause()` does not do anything (does not pause incoming `data` events) when you have `res.pipe(stream)`.  Per the [doc](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#readablepause), "The readable.pause() method has no effect if there is a 'readable' event listener."  So, apparently, `.pipe()` uses a `readable` event listener.  If you log when you are pausing the stream, log when you are resuming the stream and log when you are receiving data events, you will see that you receive data events even when you have paused the stream.

Comment: I have an implementation that uses a rolling average download rate (over the last rolling 500ms) to decide when and for how long to pause the stream.  It works pretty well when not using the `.pipe()`, but haven't figured out how to both have the `.pipe()` and pause the incoming stream.  I guess I could replace the `.pipe()` by just manually writing the incoming data to the writestream since we're already reading all the data with `data` events anyway, but then you have to implement flow/drain control on the writing to the file too.  I'll fiddle with my implementation a bit more.

Comment: I'd recommend using `.pipe()` or `.pipeline()` to chain the readable and writable streams together. Moreover, this is a good use-case for `stream`'s built-in back-pressure feature. I'd recommend injecting a stream Transform to throttle the throughput between the two streams, and let nodejs handle pause/resume

Comment: @jorgenkg - The OP already is using `.pipe()`. Please illustrate how a transform stream can be used to implement this.  FYI, it's important to note that the OP is NOT trying to slow down writing to the destination file - they are trying to slow down reading from the source to limit server bandwidth usage by any one client.

Comment: The idea is to `pipeline(downloadStream, throttle, destination)`. This works, since nodejs' built-in mechanism for throttling streams will prevent new bytes from being downloaded from `downloadStream` until the `throttle` Transfer has finished its backpressure.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thank you! Removing the pipe and manually writing to file fixed the problems with smaller files. I tried downloading a 3MB image with a speed limit of 50KB and the average was 51.6 in the end. It's not perfect and there is a lot of room for improvement but this is a nice step-up thanks to you. I am going to post the latest version as an answer and hopefully, it can still be improved.

Comment: Did you implement back-pressure on writing to the stream?  You really should do that.

Comment: Also, I think your specific application here cares more about a rolling average over the last few seconds than it does about the overall long term average throughput.  If the point here is to keep the request from hogging too much bandwidth that messes with your server latency on other types of requests, you probably don't want a 30 second request that starts out slow for 15 seconds to then be able to go as fast as it wants for the next 15 seconds, taking up all your bandwidth for 15 seconds.  Right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This type of question is bound to get opinionated answers. Personally, I would use nodejs' built-in streams capabilities to do the throttling. Observations using this approach:

- Minimal code
- The code relies on (nodejs) library code rather than custom code
- High performance. Minimal overhead, also wrt. memory
- CON: the code seems complex for those unfamiliar with streams

```js
import fs from "fs";
import https from "https";
import stream from "stream";
import util from "util";

async function downloadWithBackpressure(url, filename, byteRate) {
    let totalBytesDownloaded = 0;
    const timeBeforeStart = Date.now();

    await util.promisify(stream.pipeline)(

        // Start the download stream
        await new Promise(resolve => https.get(url, resolve)),

        // Throttle data by combining setTimeout with a stream.Transform
        new stream.Transform({
            transform: async (chunk, encoding, next) => {
                // Accumulate the total number of bytes received
                totalBytesDownloaded += chunk.byteLength;

                // Sleep to throttle towards desired transfer speed
                const sleepMs = Math.max(0, (totalBytesDownloaded / byteRate * 1000) - Date.now() + timeBeforeStart);
                sleepMs && await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, sleepMs));

                // Propagate the chunk to the stream writable
                next(null, chunk);
            }
        }),

        // Save the file to disk
        fs.createWriteStream(filename)
    );
}
```

Comment: Interesting idea.  In transforms, does it not call your transform function again until the previous one has called its callback?  And, delaying calling `next(null, chunk)` automatically throttles the upstream readStream?  I sure wish the nodejs doc was better for transforms.

Comment: FYI, I think the OP wants to regulate burst speeds (on like a 1 second rolling avg), not just long term average speed since the idea is to prevent so much bandwidth usage by this during any short period of time that the server latency suffers for other types of requests.  And, controlling that shorter term average speed is more important than the long term average.  That, I think makes the implementation a bit more work, but this direction is interesting.

Comment: First of all, thank you for taking the time to post an answer. But this solution doesn't seem to work. When I tried downloading a 5MB file with a speed limit of 50KB, the average speed was 2213 kb/s and when I tried downloading a 697 MB file with a limit of 5000 kb/s, the average was 3268 kb/s. Have you tried running this yourself?

Comment: @xeraphin - I don't think this implementation is using the same units yours is.  For example, I see them calculating bits and then comparing that to the speedLimit, but your speed limit is in bytes.

Comment: Yes, try this gist https://gist.github.com/jorgenkg/dc702582297a7514af439fa062038ea5. Which version of nodejs are you running?

Comment: @jorgenkg What unit did you use for speed limit parameter? When I send 2 as speedLimitInKB, the average is 250 kb/s (around 2000 kbps). The idea is that if a file is 5MB (5120KB), the download should take 2060 seconds because 2 kilobytes of data should be downloaded per second.

Comment: @jfriend00 You are right, I don't care about overall average speed but rather short-term limit. I made a few changes on this answer's code for that purpose and now it works as expected. The code is here: https://gist.github.com/Huseyin-Yilmaz-98/a1eed4504f2679a3adb3860879873fde I am going to do some reading on the stream api and try to fully understand the rest of the code. Thank you both!

Comment: I've updated the gist to remove _bit/byte_ confusion and included debug logging to verify it runs as expected. https://gist.github.com/jorgenkg/dc702582297a7514af439fa062038ea5

Comment: Can I test internet download speed with this approach?